# Installing a tiling window manager

Tags: release-hera, desktop, window-manager, desktop-environment

I'm running elementary os 5.1.7 Hera.I would like to install a tiling window manager,because I would be needing it frequently.I just want to know if the installation of a window manager would cause my os to break and whether i could switch between the window manager and Pantheon.Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple as that. Switch to terminal and learn how to use it. It is a must have in Linux.

```
sudo apt install nameofthewm
```

Change name of the app to the name of the Windows Manager you want to install.

If you want to remove WM. Switch to Pantheon and type:

```
sudo apt remove --purge nameofthewm
```

Comment: Will I be able to switch between it and pantheon?And how?Also,will elementary os break?

Comment: Easy. On the login screen where you type your password to login into the system in the top right corner there is a switch which allows to choose which WM you want to use. It will not break Elementary OS until you will not start modifying the configuration which can damage the system without the proper knowledge what are you doing. Standard KDE and Gnome works flawlessly. I also were using other WM like awesome and i3.

Comment: You sure about this?

Comment: Damn! For 100000% I did it many times.

Comment: OK.Thank You ;-)